# Apache Reverse Proxy in front of RD Web Access IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, remote-desktop-services, iis-8.5

I have just configured a Microsoft Remote Desktop Services service on an internal Windows Server 2012 R2 server. I have access to RDP through outside the network with port forwarding. However, because I have additional web servers running on port 80/443, I can't expose RD Web Access running on IIS to directly to the internet.

I have a reverse proxy configuration with Apache for all my internal sites, so I'm trying to use the same for RD Web Access. My configuration (for both HTTP & HTTPS) is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.xxx/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.xxx/
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration seems to work but has an issue. When connecting directly to `foo.example.com`, I get the default IIS page, as expected. However, when accessing `http://foo.example.com/RDWeb/`, the URL gets changed to `http://192.168.1.xxx/RDWeb`, which I obviously can't access from outside of my network. I need it to stay as `http://foo.example.com/RDWeb/`.

I have tried adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` to my apache configuration, when I do that, I get an infinite redirect loop, so that doesn't work either. I'm pretty sure that this is **NOT** an IIS issue, because if I set my local host file to point `foo.example.com` to `192.168.1.xxx`, it works without issue.

Is there something I'm missing in my Apache Reverse Proxy configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an epiphany, I found the cause of my issues.

Turns out, I was indeed supposed to keep `ProxyPreserveHost On` to allow URL rewriting to the correct external URL. However, because my external URL had an SSL certificate, I was getting an infinite redirect loop which went like this

```
External URL (https) -> Internal (http) -> Internal (https) -> External (https)
```

I fixed this my turning my `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives to proxy the HTTPS instead of HTTP internal IP. Because of this, I also had to add the `SSLProxyEngine On` directive.